# create windows 8 batch file to copy, rename and save files from sub directories recursively

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I'm trying to copy thousands of image files and rename them with the name of the folder they are in. The file structure is:-

```
C:\pictures\kitcam\1\master_01.jpg
C:\pictures\kitcam\1\master_02.jpg
C:\pictures\kitcam\2\master_01.jpg
C:\pictures\kitcam\3\master_01.jpg
C:\pictures\kitcam\3001\master_01.jpg
```

I would like to create a new directory `C:\pictures\kitcam\all` and copy and rename the files above to the following naming convention:-

`c:\pictures\kitcam\all\[directoryname]_filename]` 
(pad directory name to 4 digits so that the director name 1 becomes 0001 etc)

for example:-

```
C:\pictures\kitcam\all\0001_master_01.jpg
```

Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "startfolder=C:\pictures\kitcam"
SET "targetfolder=C:\pictures\kitcam\all"

FOR /r "%startfolder%" %%a IN (*.jpg) DO (
    SET "fname=%%~nxa"
    SET "fpath=%%~fa"
    FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ("%%~dpa.") DO SET "nname=000%%~nxb"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    ECHO MOVE "!fpath!" "%targetfolder%\!nname:~-4!_!fname!"
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

Look at the output and remove the word `echo` before `move` if it looks good.

Comment: wow, that's awesome, I can finally clear my iPad of all my kitcam photos - thank you so much!!!!!